# Why doesnt std::swap work on template items?

Tags: c++

Here is a simple bubble sort I'm experimenting with:

```
template<class T>
void bubbleSort(T *begin, T *end) {
    for (auto index = begin + 1; index != end; ++index) {
        for (auto bubble = begin; bubble != end - 1; ++bubble) {
            if (*bubble > *(bubble + 1)) {

                const T temp = *bubble;
                *bubble = *(bubble + 1);
                *(bubble + 1) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This version seems to work (in all its bubble-sort glory). Btw, here is the class I'm testing this against if it helps:

```
class Numbers {
    int max;
    int *numbers;

public:
    Numbers(initializer_list<int> initialList) : max { initialList.size() }, numbers { new int[max] }
    {
        int index = 0;
        for (auto it = initialList.begin(); it != initialList.end(); ++it, ++index) {
            numbers[index] = *it;
        }
    }

    int operator *(int index) { return numbers[index]; }
    int *begin() { return &numbers[0]; }
    int *end() { return &numbers[max]; }
};
```

What I was trying to do was to write the manual swap in my inner loop using `std::swap` as in:

```
for (auto bubble = begin; bubble != end - 1; ++bubble) {
    if (*bubble > *(bubble + 1)) swap (bubble, bubble + 1);
}
```

but for some reason the compiler tells me:

```
error C2665: 'std::swap' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

Why is that?

Comment: Looks like you're swapping iterators, use [`std::iter_swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap)

Comment: Oh.... that worked? Why does that work?

Comment: @sircodesalot: `iter_swap` dereferences its arguments, and then calls `std::swap`. (Also: I really hope you aren't using `bubbleSort` in production!)

Comment: @BillyONeal, nah just trying to bring myself up to speed on C++11. Noticed that the standard algorithms take iterators rather than containers, so this is my first foray into creating an iterator algorithm myself.

Comment: @sircodesalot: Ah -- well if you want to accept iterators, your template needs to be in terms of the iterator type, not a pointer. E.g. `std::map`'s iterators can never be pointers. If you need the type inside the iterators themselves, you can use `typename std::iterator_traits<YourIteratorTypeHere>::value_type`. (But you shouldn't need that with `swap` or `iter_swap`)

Comment: @BillyONeal Heh, yeah there's still a lot I don't know (like how to actually create and use an iterator properly). I'm only halfway through the new Stroustrup but I'm assuming he'll cover that at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`swap` takes its arguments by reference. In the first version of your code, you (correctly) write:

```
const T temp = *bubble;
*bubble = *(bubble + 1);
*(bubble + 1) = temp;
```

Now consider how you'd swap, for example, two integers:

```
const int temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
// or more simply
swap(a, b);
```

So your `swap` should reflect the dereferencing you did in your first correct version:

```
swap(*bubble, *(bubble + 1));
//   ^ here   ^ and here
```

Comment: No qualified call to `std::swap` (unless you really mean it). Standard idiom is `using std::swap; swap(a,b);` because of ADL (and user-provided overloads of `swap`).

Comment: @DyP Hmm you're right... I have to admit I hardly ever use ADL, you just put my nose into one of my own bad habits. :) Fixed.

Comment: Ah, it finally clicked. Just needed to stare at the example long enough. Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) is taking references as arguments.

You are giving it pointers.

You should do:

```
swap ( *bubble, *(bubble + 1) );
//     ^        ^
```

We dereference the pointers here to make it works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to dereference:

```
swap (*bubble, *(bubble + 1));
```

Comment: I thought that initially, but I was concerned it would swap the dereferenced values, rather than the actual memory locations. This works, but I don't understand why?

Comment: Your concern is correct. It swaps only values at the memory locations. For example, A = 10, B =20 yields A = 20, B = 10. But the memory location of A, B are same before and after the swap.

Comment: If you dereference a pointer in the argument list of a function that takes a reference, the pointer is converted to a reference to the same memory location.